# Why this error is showing?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm facing a strange error sometimes on my php wap site! Its not persistent, just occurs somwtimes & If I refresh page, error is went out and normal page appears. I'm attaching errors screenshot-

[image]

172 line of fun.inc.php is-

```
return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
```

I'm pasting line 164 to 212 for better understanding

```
function clean($str)
{
$str = @trim($str);
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$str = stripslashes($str);
$str = str_replace("<",'',$str);
$str = str_replace(">",'',$str);
}
return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

function regchars($word){
$chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_";
for($i=0;$i<strlen($word);$i++){
$ch = substr($word,$i,1);
$nol = substr_count($chars,$ch);
if($nol==0){
return true;
}
}
return false;
}

function nospace($word){
$pos = strpos($word," ");
if($pos === false){
return false;
}else{
return true;
}
}

function checknumber($word){
$chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$ch = substr($word,0,1);
$sres = ereg("[0-9]",$ch);
$ch = substr($word,0,1);
$nol = substr_count($chars,$ch);
if($nol==0){
return true;
}
return false;
}

function registerform($ef)
{
$errl = "";
switch($ef)
{
```

Is its a problem of my code or problem from hosting server? **How can I prevent users from showing such code??**

Comment: @AmalMurali How is this question related? That is a permission issue, this is a simple nongiven password, so PHP is stopping the usage of the escape function

Comment: The real WTF is that mysql_real_escape_string() requires a connection to MySQL to work.

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` extension use `PDO`

Comment: @siride why whould that be a wtf?

Comment: @PeeHaa: why should a function that does string manipulation require a connection to a database? It's a violation of the principle of separation of concerns. You should have to pass in the character set or use the default. It shouldn't know or care about a connection.

Comment: @netmaster - please paste errors as text, not screenshots - you can use the quote mark `>` to highlight them. If you use text, then the search engines will lead people here who are having the same problem.

Comment: @siride In order to correctly escape it needs to know the charset. trusting on some magic default charset will make it "easy" to go wrong. And you don't want that for a function introduced to protect against vulnerabilities.

Comment: @PeeHaa: and thus PHP remains a crap language.

Comment: That may be the case. And I do agree with some of PHP's crap "features" however this is just a case of `E_PEBKAC` rather than PHP being stupid again.

Comment: @siride - religious wars over languages are not helpful to the OP. They aren't going to switch on the basis you don't like X. Can you save that for the chatroom? `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

The function [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) requires a database connection, so that it can detect what character set is in use and escape correctly.

However, you should not be using that library at all - it is now deprecated. Use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli), and switch to parameterisation rather than escaping values prior to inserting them yourself.

It seems also that PHP is attempting to connect to the current database as root. Where you *do* establish a connection, bear in mind that connecting with root is a bad idea. Connect with a user having the least permissions possible for your application to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are not connected to MySQL. You can remove this function if you do not want to do something SQL queries with that.

Comment: @userNOID: I'd be helpful for me if you explain little more. Where should I put addslashes() ? And how could it prevent users from showing such Error code which (screenshot) I've given?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` needs MySQL connection. Your error message says you are not connected to MySQL successfully. If you still be unconnected, replace `mysql_real_escape_string()` with `addslashes()`

Comment: let me try your advice, In while do you've any suggestion If such long error can be prevented to showing users? Like- showing a small error, if db not connected accidentally...

Comment: Don't use `addslashes` instead of SQL escaping. Fix your SQL escaping or don't do it at all. The string probably shouldn't be SQL escaped there in the first place.

Comment: Also you can remove this function, it's just SQL injection prevention.

Comment: Why are you answering such questions? In the error message you can read "access denied"... we should really take care for the quality of SO, otherwise the side will die :-(

Comment: @userNOID - I believe `addslashes` is not a sufficient replacement for `mysql_real_escape_string` in all cases. If this old library _must_ be used then the proper escape function must be used as well.